# How to print out all request headers of HTTP requests on the server side?

Tags: linux, proxy, http, haproxy, http-headers

I have a HAProxy configuration which balances requests to many servers. I want to compare the outgoing request headers when requests go thru HAProxy to the ones I would make directly to my servers. For example, I want to test if my HAProxy configuration uses cookies with the client without leaking them to the outgoing servers.

What tool could I use to easily compare those headers? Is there something better than configuring Apache or nginx to log all headers?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do might be to run `pcap` on your haproxy server. Then you can analyze the output later with WireShark or something similar.